# Boundary of the limit when $a<<1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, approximation

Let's say I have the expression $-b+\frac{3}{2}b\cdot a^2$. Can I say that by taking the limit when $a<<1$, that expression is $\approx -b$ ? can a constant number, like $\frac{3}{2}$ can "ruin" the limit?

Thanks.

Comment: $a \to 0$ maybe?

Comment: Well, another question that popped into my mind: is saying that $a<<1$ is equivalent to saying that $a\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: In general settings, if you are in the world of real number and you variable is positive, I will say yes. In other context may be inappropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer might be yes. You may observe that
$$
-b+\frac{3}{2}b\cdot a^2=-b\left(1-\frac{3a^2}{2}\right)
$$ giving, as $a \to 0$,
$$
-b+\frac{3}{2}b\cdot a^2\approx-b
$$ since$$ \left(1-\frac{3a^2}{2}\right) \to 1.$$